# What do the first two say?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Three children walk into the kitchen, Mom asks each one **in turn** "Does everybody want juice?". The third child says "yes" , what does the first two say? 

My thinking:
`The first child says:"Yes, if and only if, child two and child three says yes"
The second child says: "Yes, if and only if the third child says yes"`
Due to the statements made by child 1 and 2, if child three says 'yes' , then child two would also say 'yes' and that would make child 1 also want juice , hence when mom asks child three , his response would be true.If mom asks child 1 first, then he cant possibly know if child two or three wants juice , and so he can only answer for himself. Knowing this, he decides to base his response on the response of the other two, and 'two' decides to base his response on the response that three will give. N.B. Mom asks **each one** if **everybody** wants juice.

My Teachers thinking:
`child 1:I dont know
child 2:I dont know`

To me, this sort of makes sense, because if 1 and 2 are unsure , then three saying yes will mean that all three want juice. But, this is not the answer(to me) , because this cannot be represented logically(what symbol is used for "i dont know").

Which, if any would you go with? Is there any way to properly determine what they would say?

Comment: It depends on what the children are allowed to say. If they are just able to say yes/no/don't-know, then your teacher is correct. Though without knowing their language, all you can say yourself is "Don't know" :-)

Comment: An extensive discussion of this occurs in the comments [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3451).

Comment: Having three child I know the answer by several years experimenting.  There are two possibilities. Possibility 1: they say "Yes. Yes. Yes" and Possibility 2: they say "No. No. No". Since the last one said "Yes", it is the first solution :)

Comment: "Does everybody want juice?" is just another way of asking "do you want juice?". So the fact that the third child said "yes" doesn't mean anything; the other two children could have said "no". The "everybody" in the sentence does not really mean "everybody" in normal usage.

Answer (score 1):

$\rightarrow$When mom asks the 1st child, he says I don't know. This is because he himself needs the juice but he doesn't know whether the next two children need it or not.

He can't say YES because he doesn't know the requirements of the next two children. If the 1st child did not need the juice then he could have simply said NO as the answer. This would mean that 'EVERYBODY does not need juice', which will be true if the 1st child doesn't need it.

Thus his reply ' I don't know' states that he needs it.

$\rightarrow$Similarly the 2nd child's reply 'I don't know' means he needs the juice, but he doesn't know about the 3rd child's requirements.

$\rightarrow$Finally when the 3rd child says YES, it means all of them need juice, since 1st and 2nd have already agreed. Note that if 3rd didn't need juice he could have stated NO.

Comment: "Thus his reply ' I don't know' states that he needs it." --- It may equally mean that (s)he does not want it, but still does not know about the others.

Comment: If he does not need it, then he will say NO. Because if he does not it then the answer to "Does EVERYBODY needs juice?" will be NO. Thus "i don't know" specifically says that he needs juice, but he doesn't know about the 3rd child.

Comment: It makes sense. The children must have taken PhD in logic :)

Comment: But why is it incorrect that the first says "if and only if the other two says yes", etc...  Wont that be that same as what you said, i.e. he doesnt decide and lets the decision fall ultimately on the third child

Comment: let p be the statement-"every body wants juice" , q- "child 1 wants juice " r-"child 2 wants juice " , s-"child 3 wants juice"... then the statement: p IFF q^r^s would mean that if q = f and r= f and s= f , then p would still be true. Am i right? Then this would prove that my thinking is incorrect.

Comment: what is f? Does it stand for False?

Comment: @worlboss I think  it will be 'if' and the 'only if' part will not be there i.e. the 1st child will say "Yes if 2nd and 3rd child say Yes". Similarly for the 2nd child.

Comment: looking at the truth table for if(implies), if child one and two says no , then the statement p will sitll be true, i.e. they all want juice.

Comment: You have to consider the question carefully. Since  we have the word "Everybody" in the question, even if any one child does not need juice the answer will be No. Thus, if 1st child says NO (which will be the case if he does not need juice), then p can't be true.